# Como verificar se uma coluna(variável) existe dentro de um 'data.frame'?

Tags: r

Preciso verificar se existem colunas (ou seja variáveis) dentro de um `data.frame` antes de fazer qualquer operação, porém a variável passada não está em `string` para comparar com o `colnames` ou `names`.

Segue o código:

```
check_measurement_ages = function(data_base,measurement_variable1,measurement_variable2){
  if(measurement_variable1 %in% names(data_base)){
}
```

Comment: Não entendi. Tua pergunta ficou ambígua para mim. Tu precisa verificar se existe alguma coluna (alguma no sentido de qualquer uma) no data frame ou precisa procurar uma coluna específica? Se for uma coluna específica, como identificá-la? O que ela tem de especial para diferenciá-la das outras colunas que porventura existem neste data frame?

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é relacionado a [`non-standard evaluation`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html).

O menor exemplo possível de fazer isso é:

```
verificar_coluna <- function(data, coluna){
  coluna_texto <- deparse(substitute(coluna))
  coluna_texto %in% names(data)
}

> verificar_coluna(mtcars, mpg)
[1] TRUE
```

A função `substitute` captura a expressão digitada pelo usuário, e a função `deparse` a transforma em string.

O problema dessa abordagem é se a tua função for chamada por dentro de uma outra:

```
verificar_coluna2 <- function(data, coluna){
  verificar_coluna(data, coluna)
}

> verificar_coluna2(mtcars, mpg)
[1] FALSE
```

Por isso uma abordagem mais segura é proposta pelo pacote `lazyeval`. A [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html) dele é bem explicativa.

Na prática, é melhor escrever uma função:

```
verificar_coluna <- function(data, coluna){
  coluna_texto <- lazyeval::expr_text(coluna)
  coluna_texto %in% names(data)
}
```

Assim as duas funções irão funcioanr.

```
> verificar_coluna(mtcars, mpg)
[1] TRUE
> verificar_coluna2(mtcars, mpg)
[1] TRUE
```